# Move chapter to top and change its format

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I would like to change position of my chapter title more to the top of the page and also change format of it to: "0 Introduction"
"1 Something"
"1.1 Something"
"2 Something"
etc. instead of "Chapter 1 - Something"

[image: Desription of what I want to do]

and also, how do I change the distance between chapter title and beginning of the text?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) with the `section` chapter style.

```
% chapstyleprob.tex  SE 567585
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{section} %% this seems to be the style you want
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-1cm} %% raise title, adjust to suit
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}  %% first chapter number will be 0
\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]